# Issuies with the fibonacci series and c

Tags: c, math

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int fib();
int scan;

int main() {
    scanf("%d", &scan);

    printf("%d\n", fib());


    scanf("%s");
    return 0;
}

int fib() {
    return floor((pow(1+sqrt(5)/2, scan)-(-pow(1-sqrt(5)/2, scan)))/sqrt(5));
}
```

I'm pretty new to programming with C and decided to try and calculate any number in the Fibonacci series. I based it off of my lua script [here](https://gist.github.com/preprocessor/6979752). I'm at a loss of what I've done wrong, could someone give me some insight?

Comment: `1 + sqrt(5)/2  -->  (1 + sqrt(5))/2`

Answer (score 2):

You have the formula wrong. You want fib to be:

```
int fib() {
    return round((pow((1+sqrt(5))/2, scan)-(-pow((1-sqrt(5))/2, scan)))/sqrt(5));
}
```

instead. You were missing parenthesis around the `1+sqrt(5)` and `1-sqrt(5)` terms and were using floor instead of round, which was underestimating the fibonacci numbers in my tests. (This mostly has to do with low precision in the `pow` function. The seventh fibonacci number, 13, came out to 12.969)

You also probably want to change

```
scanf("%s");
```

to

```
char tmp;
scanf("%c", &tmp);
```

Since the way you have it incorrectly omits an argument.

Hope this helps!